# Why Malyavaan & Asumbanan were certified by Sita along with Vibhishana that they are good souls?

Tags: ramayana, sita

When Sita was in Ashoka vana, she praised Vibhishana along with Malyavaan and Asumbana.  This appears in `Sundar Kand` (not clear under which sarga). I was able to find a [site](https://sundaragandam.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/chapter-21sitas-reply-to-ravana) which hosts English translation:

> Is there no saint or learned person in this country who can advice you
>   and put you in right path. I can't say like that, considering the
>   fact great people like Vibhishana, Asumbanan, Malyavan are residing
>   here. Don’t you listen to them. Do not ignore the words of learned
>   people and indulge in a sinful activity. You are paving way for
>   destruction of yourself and your country.

What are those good deeds performed by the duo who was in par with Vibhishana in the mind of Sita?

Comment: I think Sita was just praising them because they at least tried to persuade Ravana to do the right thing.

Comment: Vibheshan did the right thing and helped Rama ! while asumbayan and malyavan keptquitet , they werewathching from the sky the backstabbing by vibheshan ! but they kept quiet !

Comment: Sita doesn't speak about Malyavan and Visumbanan in the sundarakanda. She only speaks about Vibhishana. You can refer Valmikiramayana.net it has english translations along with itrans transliteration.

Answer (score 2):

Sita Devi didn't name Vibhishana, Malyavan, Asumbanan or any other one while replying to Ravana in the Sundara Kanda.

The dialogue quoted in the between Ravana and Sita Devi occurs in the Sundara Kanda chapter 20, 21. Ravana speaks in the chapter 20 and Sita devi replies in the next chapter. The original verse for which you have posted translation is from [*Sundara Kanda sarga 21 shloka 9-10*](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga21/sundarasans21.htm#Verse9).

> इह सन्तो न वा सन्ति सतो वा नानुवर्तसे || ५-२१-९ 
>   तथाहि विपरीता ते बुद्धिराचारवर्जिता |
>
> Here are there not good people? Or are you not following those who are good? It must be like that because your mind, devoid of traditions is perverse.

She just meant good people during her conversation. She was not sure who were good or bad people in detail when she was talking this to Ravana. So, it is the translator who added these names while they were translating the original Sanskrit verse.

---

However, the people mentioned in the verse were of good qualities unlike the other rakshasas. They advised Ravana to make peace with Lord Rama and return Sita to Him. Here's what Vibhishana advised his elder brother Ravana regarding this issue.

> Even before arrows resembling thunder bolts and with a speed equal to wind, dispatched by Rama, take away the heads of chiefs of demons, give back Sita to Rama. [[6-14-4]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga14/yuddhasans14.htm#Verse4)
>
> Even if you are protected by the sun god, or by Maruts (storm gods) nor even seated in the lap of Indra or god of Death nor if you have penetrated into the regions of heaven or under the earth you will not be spared by the arrows of Rama. [[6-14-6]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga14/yuddhasans14.htm#Verse6)

Ravana turned a deaf ear to his words. From Yuddha Kanda Sarga 35,

Similarly, Malyavan, maternal grandfather of Ravana also advised the same.

> I deem Rama of firm fortitude as Vishnu dwelling in human form. This Rama is not a mere human being, he by whom that most wonderful bridge was built across the sea. O, Ravana! **Conclude peace with Rama, who is the king of men. Having come to know of his acts, let that which is good for the future be done after a mature understanding**. [[6-35-36]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga35/yuddhasans35.htm#Verse36)

Ravana also abuses him and turns his deaf ear. He gets ready for a war with Rama.

<sup>I couldn't find reference to Asumbanan in Ramayana. If there's a name variant, someone please let me know</sup>